# moving to new tag with gbp buildpackage

Tags: packaging, git-buildpackage

I'm trying to repackage something that is being maintained in a git repo, and has a now-out-of-date debian package existing.  I followed [these instructions](http://honk.sigxcpu.org/projects/git-buildpackage/manual-html/gbp.import.html#GBP.IMPORT.UPSTREAM-GIT) with the exception of [turning off pristine-tar support](https://www.preining.info/blog/2014/06/debian-pristine-tar-packaging/).

*But:* running `gbp buildpackage` results in the error:

`gbp:error: upstream/0.8.0 is not a valid treeish`

In my repo, `upstream` is the remote repository I cloned; `v0.8.0` is a tag; and in `debian/gbp.conf` I have `git-upstream-tag = v%(version)s` but it still seems I don't have it configured to find the right treeish.  If I `git checkout -b upstream/0.8.0 v0.8.0` to create a branch with that name, everything proceeds just as I'd expect.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git-upstream-tag = v%(version)s
```

should be

```
upstream-tag = v%(version)s
```

according to gbp.conf(5):

> key=value pairs of the command sections reflect the command line options and their settings. For example gbp-buildpackage(1) manualpage contains the  --git-export-dir=diirectory option which can be turned into configuration file setting by dropping the --git prefix with:
>
> ```
>       [buildpackage]
>       export-dir = directory
> ```